# Почему регулярное выражение "[ !,]+" работает так?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

      String s = "Hello! My name is, John";
      String[] parts = s.split("[ !,]+");
      for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
          System.out.println(parts[i]);
      }

    }
```

Почему, если я пишу рег.выражение как: `"[ !,]+"`, то выводится без пробелов:

```
Hello
My
name
is
John
```

А если убераю знак `"+"`, `"[ !,]"`, то пробелы остаются:

```
Hello

My
name
is

John
```

Знаю что плюс означает, что символ может встречаться один и более раз, но не пойму, как это влияет на пробелы!

Comment: На примере кусочка `Hello! My` — с плюсом делится по подстроке `! ` (с пробелом, потому что «один и более раз») и получается массив из двух строк, а без плюса делится два раза по символу `!` и по символу ` ` (пробелу) и получается массив из трёх строк (вторая строка — пустая, поэтому println выводит пустоту между Hello и My)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция разделения строки рассматривает регулярное выражение как сигнал к отсечки строки. Из примера вывода видно что в обоих случаях элементы результирующего массива не имеют пробелов, но если убран "+" в результате просто появляются пустые строки как отдельные элементы результирующего массива. Это происходит потому что функция разделения строк отсекает следующую строку при первом же удовлетворении регулярного выражения. Таким образом регулярное выражение "[ !,]" для строки вида "!," срабатывает на первом и втором символе, следовательно функция split создаст массив в 2мя элементами из пустых строк.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ты не отличаешь пробелы от пустых строк. Пробелы по-прежнему исчезают, но между пробелом и восклицательным знаком ничего нет - вот оно и остаётся.